# yii2 advance id menu

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i am trying to create if else in my controller but have no idea how can id do that here is my Controller and menu code given bellow there 
my requirement is in about page how can i show that all 3 quires but when i try i can show only one by one i want to do that because i just wanna show documents by group in same page so is that possible ?

### so is that else statement possible to check with array if yes how can i Because i have bunch of id which i have to check

here is my about Controller

```
public function actionAbout($id = null){
        // join with other table by province
        if ($id  == '15' )  {
          $query = bio::find()
            ->joinWith('wat')
            ->where(['wat.province' => $id ]);
        }
        // join with other table by amphur
        if ($id  == array('178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183'))  {
          $query = bio::find()
            ->joinWith('wat')
            ->where(['wat.amphur' => $id ]);
        }else{
        // ///////// like menu list //////////
          $query = Bio::find()
            ->where(['LIKE', 'rolerule', $id]);
        }
        // $query = Bio::find()->orderBy('bio_id DESC')->where(['status' => 1]);
        $countQuery = clone $query;
          $pages = new Pagination(['defaultPageSize' => 30 ,'totalCount' => $countQuery->count()]);
          $models = $query->offset($pages->offset)
            ->limit($pages->limit)
            ->all();

        return $this->render('about', [
          'records' => $models,
          'pages' => $pages,
        ]);
      }
```

here is my about menu

```
<a href="#demo2" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">provience</a>
<div class="collapse" id="demo2">
  <a href="about?id=178" class="list-group-item"> provience </a>
</div>
<a href="#demo3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Amphur</a>
<div class="collapse" id="demo3">
  <a href="about?id=178" class="list-group-item"> Amphur </a>
  <a href="about?id=179" class="list-group-item"> muang</a>
  <a href="about?id=180" class="list-group-item"> test1</a>
  <a href="about?id=181" class="list-group-item"> test2</a>
  <a href="about?id=182" class="list-group-item"> test3</a>
  <a href="about?id=183" class="list-group-item"> test4</a>
</div>
<a href="#demo4" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">hero</a>
<div class="collapse" id="demo4">
  <a href="about?id=hero" class="list-group-item">hero</a>
  <a href="about?id=superman" class="list-group-item">superman</a>
  <a href="about?id=batman" class="list-group-item">batman</a>
  <a href="about?id=ironman" class="list-group-item">ironman</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get only the last query because you reassign it then

Assuming you can test    $your_test_var against you_value this coulb be a suggestion

```
public function actionAbout($id = null){
        // join with other table by province
        if ($your_test_var == 'your_first_val' )  {
          $query = bio::find()
            ->joinWith('wat')
            ->where(['wat.province' => $id ]);

        }
      // join with other table by amphur
        if ($your_test_var == 'your_second_val' )  {
         $query = bio::find()
           ->joinWith('wat')
           ->where(['wat.amphur' => $id ]);
        } else {
      // ///////// like menu list //////////
      $query = Bio::find()
        ->where(['LIKE', 'rolerule', $id]);
      }
    // $query = Bio::find()->orderBy('bio_id DESC')->where(['status' => 1]);
     $countQuery = clone $query;
     $pages = new Pagination(['defaultPageSize' => 30 ,'totalCount' => $countQuery->count()]);
     $models = $query->offset($pages->offset)
         ->limit($pages->limit)
         ->all();

     return $this->render('about', [
          'records' => $models,
          'pages' => $pages,
     ]);
 }
```

Comment: it works but how can i send my value in 2nd statement i have got bunch of id so how can i check it?
`  // join with other table by amphur
        if ($id  == '178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188' )  {
         $query = bio::find()
           ->joinWith('wat')
           ->where(['wat.amphur' => $id ]);
        } else {`

Comment: Please  .. update your question with the proper code and the explain you question ... in comment is impossible undertsand code .. and what you are looking for now ..

Comment: i mean it that possible to check if condition in array?

Comment: You can check a value of an array in a if condition .. eg: if ($array[3] == 'my_value') .. otherwise please explain better . your question .